# I have a Broan-NuTone AER110LK Bathroom Fan with LED Light that I am installing to a single pole switch. Need help with wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom-fixtures

I have a Broan-NuTone AER110LK Bathroom Fan with LED Light that I am installing to a single pole switch. Not 100% on wiring because instructions only show wiring for a two function switch. Wire from switch is black,white and copper. Wires from bath fan and light are black, green and white.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Take the black wires from the light and the fan and connect them to the black wire from the switch. Take the white wires from the light and fan and connect them to the white wire from the switch. Take the green wires from the light and fan and connect them to the bare copper wire from the switch.

With this configuration, the light and fan will operate when the switch is turned on. They cannot be operated independently unless you add another switch and add to or replace the existing wire from the switch

Comment: Greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since you are controlling all fan functionality with a single switch, you will splice both the light feed and fan feed to the black wire. In your case this will provide voltage to both components when you turn on the switch. (IF you had 2 switches or a dual control switch, the fan black would go to switch black and the light's black would go to the other switch or dual switch red).
Summary:
Splice the 3 white wires together (1 from switch, 1 from light, 1 from fan)
Splice the 3 greens together (switch/feed ground, light ground, fan ground)
Splice the 3 blacks together (switch black, light's black, fan black)